# Simultaneous Running HAXM AVD Emulator Limit

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-testing, haxm

To elaborate on the title, I'm running many simultaneous AVD's for my automated build/test processes (think concurrent builds for a project, or multiple projects building at once). Most problems that people have with running multiple HAXM accelerated AVD's at once is memory related. THIS IS NOT MY PROBLEM (I think). I have a pretty beefy i7 machine with 32gb of ram. When installing HAXM, I allocated 28gb (sorry, I can't post more pictures without more rep).

Here is my AVD configuration(s). Observe, only 1024mb of memory allocated per emulator:

AVD Config:

[image]

Here are my system specs:

OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name DUCHT1-DS1
System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
System Model    OptiPlex 7040
System Type x64-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Dell Inc. 1.2.8, 1/26/2016
SMBIOS Version  2.8
Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.1.7601.17514"
User Name   Not Available
Time Zone   Central Daylight Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 32.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   31.9 GB
Available Physical Memory   29.5 GB
Total Virtual Memory    63.8 GB
Available Virtual Memory    61.2 GB
Page File Space 31.9 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys

I can run 8 emulators at once, I would post an image if I could. I'm only using ~16gb of my 32gb of ram when they're all running. (2048mb per emulator at this moment in time). No matter what I do, I cannot run more than 8 emulators. I can run 8 emulators with 1gb, 2gb, or 3gb memory allocated per device simultaneously. I've tried 32bit vs 64bit intel images. There is clearly a limit beyond that of memory that is enforcing this.

The error message I get when starting my 9th emulator (Note, I started counting emulators at 0):

9th emulator boot error

[image]

"Failed to create HAX VM. No accelerator found."

The only thing I could think of where the number 8 might be coming from would be the fact I have 4 cores == 8 logical processors. That's a wild guess though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to a [hardcoded variable](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/140) in the HAXM. You can solve this problem by downloading the [latest HAXM from the Github page](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases), which will set an limit of 64 guests instead of 8.

Comment: I haven't been able to test this, but it's pretty clear this is the solution I was after (3 years ago). Regardless, thanks so much! Much appreciated. Clearly, I should have opened an issue against the intel/haxm repo immediately, as they were able to port in a fix within a few months. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

Type this in the command line:

```
sc stop intelhaxm
```

then:

```
sc start intelhaxm
```

And then your emulator should work.

Comment: But I only run into the issue after starting my 9th AVD. 8 of them come up fine with HAXM acceleration. I should run this prior to starting all my emulators?