# What is the max number of Android emulators running with intel HAXM on the same PC?

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I want to get as many emulators running at the same time as I can.
But somehow only the first 8 emulators can run with intel HAXM acceleration support. After that, any emulators are started with a warning that HAXM is not working, and they will be running very slow, even though I adjust the max memory of HAXM.

I tried with a Mac and a Win PC, both max emulators were 8. I do have a lot of memory left, so would like to run more with HAXM.

Is there a place I can configure HAXM to support more emulators?

Comment: How many cores do your machines have?

Comment: This Q is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910107/simultaneous-running-haxm-avd-emulator-limit

Comment: @dmark: Which version of HAXM have you installed? Please provide this information. Is it < 6.0.3?

Comment: @LeonardoAcevedo My Mac has 4 cores, and PC has 8 cores.

Comment: @MWiesner Yes, very similar to that one. But I still can get the 9th boot up, only without Haxm. It seems he did not get a solution yet.

Comment: @MWiesner I am using the Version 6.0.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simultaneous Running HAXM AVD Emulator Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910107/simultaneous-running-haxm-avd-emulator-limit)

Answer (score 0):

To allocate more memory to HAXM rerun the HAXM installer once again.

For more info refer [Installation instructions for HAXM on mac](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)

Comment: I have 12 GB memory allocated to HAXM, not working. Each emulator takes about 500 MB, eight emulators end up taking only 4 GB. It does not seem like memory problem.